# A measure for which Lusin's theorem fails?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, measurable-functions, borel-measures

Lusin's theorem states that if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue measurable function, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a compact subset $E$ of $[a,b]$ whose complement has Lebesgue measure less than $\epsilon$ and a function $g$ continuous relative to $E$ such that $f=g$ on $E$.  My question is, what is an example of a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ for which this is not true?

I know that it's true for all Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$ which assign finite measure to all bounded intervals, so a counterexample would either have to be a non-Borel measure or a Borel measure which assigns infinite measure to some bounded intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) and the indicator function of the rationals.

Comment: I'm maybe missing something obvious, but I don't see how the counting measure can provide the example. Lusin happens inside a set of finite measure, which in this case will be finite; and any function is continuous on a finite set.

Comment: What needs to be finite (in fact, less than $\varepsilon$) is the measure of $E^c$. If the counting measure of $E^c$ is less than $1$, then $E^c$ is actually empty.